# Encapsulated query within a database object returns too few rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

A member of my team has gotten some strange behaviour which can be recreated both in the development environment and the system test environment MS SQL databases.

If he runs this query directly it returns **517 rows**, which is the correct and expected result:

```
SELECT 
        p.package_id, la.CODE_KID
    FROM package p with (nolock), Strength s with (nolock),
    ProductCODE la  with (nolock), CODE  a with (nolock)
    where p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
    and la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
    AND la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
    except 
    select p.package_ID, p.CODE_KID from package p
```

However, if he puts the same query in a view it wrongly returns **311 rows** - **206 rows** less than if he runs the query directly.

If we run the Query Analyser for both the direct query and the view query we see that the two query plans are quite different, but we don't understand why.

He also tried to dump the query into a temporary table:

```
insert into MyDB.CODE_PACKAGE
    SELECT 
            p.package_id, la.CODE_KID
        FROM package p with (nolock), Strength s with (nolock),
        ProductCODE la  with (nolock), CODE  a with (nolock)
        where p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
        and la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
        AND la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
        except 
        select p.package_ID, p.CODE_KID from package p
```

, which correctly creates a table that has **517 rows**. However, if he puts the same SQL in a stored procedure it wrongly returns **311 rows**.

It seems that once the query is encapsulated within a database object it returns too few rows.

As mentioned, he has recreated the error on other database systems too.

Any ideas what can cause this strange behaviour?

He has also tried the following without any success:

- Remove the `nolock`
- Set transaction isolation level to read uncommitted

**Update**

I'm not sure if the SSMS Wizard or Template was used to create the view, but if I select "Script View as -> CREATE to -> New Query Editor Window" then this is the output:

```
USE [TestUtv]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE view [MyDBviews].[CODE_PACKAGE]
as

    SELECT 
            p.package_id, la.CODE_KID
        FROM package p with (nolock), Strength s with (nolock),
        ProductCODE la  with (nolock), CODE  a with (nolock)
        where p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
        and la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
        AND la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
        except 
        select p.package_ID, p.CODE_KID from package p

GO
```

Here is one of the tables that is used, unfortunately there database is quite huge with hundreds of tables and views so I can't post everything here.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Package](
    [Package_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Multiple] [int] NULL,
    [Multiple2] [int] NULL,
    [OutProdnum] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [OutProdnumDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [zzzPackage_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Strength_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Indi] [varchar](4096) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LastChangedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastChangedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CODE_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [MarkDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
    [KIPackage_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [xyz] [bit] NULL,
    [Ean] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [D_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [abc_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DDD] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [era_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [uuu] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [ueer_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [abcIdString] [varchar](4095) NULL,
    [ExternalId] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Dpack_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tttpacks_KID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Package_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Package_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Interesting and intriguing. How are you creating the view and/or sproc?

Comment: @Leo All work is done within MS SQL Management Studio.

Comment: when you say that all work is done through SSMS, are you refering to wizards or templates? it'd be good to post the t-sql that creates the view

Comment: Are you sure the query is executed in the same database as the view/stored procedure? Also, could you post the code for the view and the query plans for both the query and view.

Comment: @Leo See my update, thank you.

Comment: @JodyT Yes, the direct query is executed on the same database as the view/stored procedure. See the update for the view.

Comment: What is the schema of tables `package`, `Strength`, etc. accessed by the view? What happens if you create the view within the same schema that these tables belong to?

Comment: As noted by other comment. The schema `[MyDBviews]` is different. The view might be accessing a complete different object

Comment: @Leo Its the correct object, the views have different names, ex. `employeeViews.Salaries`, `boatViews.Brands`, according to their domain. In the OP `MyDB.CODE_PACKAGE` is the table, in my update is the View, so the naming is different. all the views and tables are in the same database, though.

Comment: What other objects are there inside `[MyDBviews]`? Perhaps a view with the same name as one of the tables accessed by the view?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen I tried to repro your case in my DB. I simple wrote `select * from table` and got 2278 records... Then wrote the same query in a view, and executed that.. and I got same no of records there too..

Comment: Are there `nulls` in the results? I suppose setting `ANSI_NULLS ON` will cut off results that should otherwise be equal.

Comment: @xpy Setting it to OFF has no effect. Same with quoted identifiers.

Comment: Are the plans same for both the query and the view?

Comment: @No, as I mentioned in the OP they are different, but we don't understand why.

Comment: What are the differences? Are other indexes chosen? Are there filtered indexes? Are all the statistics updated?

Comment: @xpy As mentioned in the OP, the same error has been recreated on other database systems so we don't believe that the error is with a faulty index. The statistics are updated regularly and the indexes are the same on all database systems.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos See my update. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90206/discussion-between-xpy-and-inge-henriksen).

Comment: I would suggest preceding every table in the query by its schema, i.e. `dbo`, like: `FROM dbo.package, dbo.Strength, dbo.ProductCODE etc`. Then use this exact query in the view as well.

Comment: Encapsulating a query in a view shouldn't change the explain plan. Are you sure that the select and view are querying fro the same tables ?  Perhaps there is a duplication of a table, or from different environments.

Comment: @Amir Yes, we are sure that they are querying the same views and tables. Thank you.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I don't think the naming of the tables and views are the problem since we have confirmed that we indeed are querying the same tables and views.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos 100% I have confirmed it and also another person on the team has confirmed it. The other guy has worked 20+ years with SQL and I have worked 15+ years.

Comment: If the plan sql server uses is doubted, than use this : ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT

Comment: I wonder if the fact that the same alias (`p`) is used in both queries (the "outer" select and the "except" select) is somehow causing trouble. Also, it would be useful if you could create a MCVE, maybe on SQLFiddle. In order to make it *M*inimal, try removing the most obvious suspects first: `except` part, hints, joins (1 at a time...) until it is "fixed".

Comment: @GuidoG I think `ARITHABORT` is by default `ON` in MS SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @Amit I unsuccessfully renamed all of the aliases now.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen - sorry the aliases didn't prove useful. you should still create a MCVE, otherwise it looks like nobody is able to assist.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen  I'm curious: a) version of SQLServer, b) what will become if you exclude join with CODE table from your query? c) what will become if you rewrite `EXCEPT` for `NOT EXISTS` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try incapsulating your query in an SP and/or a Function and compare the numbers of records returned.
What you are seeing is likely impacted by connection ANSI settings. SSMS and SQL Server sets some by default on each connection and Objects like views have them set at creation time and persisted at execution time.
Check the options currently enabled for your sessions:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/

Check options that are persisted with your view:

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules

Answer (score 0):

Try the same query using JOIN statements. you can end up with different results from different query plans on queries that use this older joining technique.

```
SELECT 
    p.package_id, 
    la.CODE_KID
FROM package p with (nolock)
INNER JOIN Strength s with (nolock)
    ON p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
INNER JOIN ProductCODE la with (nolock)
    ON la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
INNER JOIN CODE a with (nolock)
    ON la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    p.package_ID, 
    p.CODE_KID 
FROM package p
```

Comment: Your proposal still returns 311 rows. Thanks though.

Comment: Change the inner joins to LEFT OUTER.  You might have a missing value throwing the join off

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following syntax for what you are trying to accomplish. My guess is the old ANSI JOIN Syntax you are using breaks somehow when creating a stored procedure.

```
SELECT 
    p.package_id 
    ,la.CODE_KID
FROM package AS p
JOIN Strength AS s ON p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
JOIN ProductCODE AS la ON la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
JOIN CODE AS a ON la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
EXCEPT 
SELECT p.package_ID, p.CODE_KID from package p
```

Answer (score 0):

The really question is, which recods are filtered out if the query is incapsulated into a view?

so, as @Alex suggested before, you should compare results from your query and the same query in the view.

in SSMS try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.package_id, la.CODE_KID
    FROM package p with (nolock), Strength s with (nolock),
    ProductCODE la  with (nolock), CODE  a with (nolock)
    where p.Strength_ID = s.Strength_ID
    and la.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
    AND la.CODE_KID = a.CODE_ID
    except 
    select p.package_ID, p.CODE_KID from package p
    ) AS DIRECT_Q
FULL JOIN
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM YOUR_VIEW_CREATED_FROM_QUERY    /* <-- THE NAME OF YOUR VIEW */
    ) AS VIEWED_Q
ON DIRECT_Q.package_id=VIEWED_Q.package_id 
   AND DIRECT_Q.CODE_KID=VIEWED_Q.CODE_KID
```

in this way you will see which records are missing and try to understand the reason (nulls, accents, particular characters ecc ecc)

I will also give a check if **datatype** and **collation** for package.CODE_KID and ProductCODE.CODE_KID are the same.